# Running P3D Processing sketch in JAR file, using Netbeans

Tags: opengl, netbeans, processing, jogl

I know there is a way to program with Processing P3D in an external IDE.

I have successfully been able to run 2D and P3D sketches within NetBeans IDE. But if I build the project to a JAR file with Processing P3D in my sketch, and try to run the JAR file, I get this error:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\*****\natives\windows-i586\\gluegen-rt.dll
```

What can I do about this in order to make a Processing P3D sketch run in a JAR file?
I know it has something to do with the JOGL library Processing uses, but I don’t know how to satisfy the error.

Sketch running fine in netbeans:

[Processing P3D sketch running fine in netbeans 11.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLUrI.jpg)

Sketch running as JAR file in Windows Powershell... :

[Processing P3D sketch running as JAR file in Windows Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzzlS.jpg)

Full error:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\*****\natives\windows-i586\\gluegen-rt.dll
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:624)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:63)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:106)
        at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:487)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:421)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:317)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:287)
        at com.jogamp.nativewindow.NativeWindowFactory$2.run(NativeWindowFactory.java:183)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.nativewindow.NativeWindowFactory.<clinit>(NativeWindowFactory.java:180)
        at com.jogamp.newt.NewtFactory$1.run(NewtFactory.java:68)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.jogamp.newt.NewtFactory.<clinit>(NewtFactory.java:65)
        at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initIcons(PSurfaceJOGL.java:498)
        at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL.initFrame(PSurfaceJOGL.java:134)
        at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:11035)
        at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10922)
        at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10657)
        at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10639)
        at com.JSF.processing.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Comment: You need to modify the Ant script of your project to include the content of jogamp-fat.jar into your fat JAR. You can look at my script, especially the target named "create-jars": http://svn.code.sf.net/p/tuer/code/pre_beta/build.xml

Comment: By the way, I use nsis-ant in JNDT, maybe it could be helpful for you...

Comment: Ok. my project is using Maven. So how would i do that / would i be able to do that in Maven?

Comment: Maybe it's doable with Maven but it might be very complicated because it's not the right tool to do that. Rather use Ant or Gradle when you need something more flexible. I use those three tools, I'm not very biased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I figured it out! I put all of the JAR files into a folder and added them to the class-path via Ant.

Next I used ant to create a fat JAR with all of the classes in the classpath including the source code

I ran the Jar in Windows powershell, and it works perfectly!